# Who voiced the racist cop on NWA's 'F*ck tha Police'?

Tags: hip-hop, rap

In the original song there is the mock trial of a racist cop

> "That's a lie. That's a Goddamn lie!"

etc at about *4:53*.

I don't think that these lines are recorded by any of the NWA members (Ice Cube, MC Ren, and then Eazy-E) and it sounds too integrated into the song to be a sample.

Does anyone know who provided these lines?

Thanks

Comment: I always assumed it was Ice Cube because the voice sounds like an affected 'white' accent to me and has the tone and timbre of Cube. But there doesn't really seem to be a source for this that I can find, so far...

Answer (score 1):

My understanding (and I can't pull up a footnote, sorry) was that was one of the group's (white) producers/business associates pulled into the studio for a cameo.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to my ear like the actor Vincent Donoffrio.
He played a racist cop in Strange Days w Angela Basset and RalFiennes. He’s got a very specific voice though I dunno if he’d ever want the official credit for being the voice